# Sampling files from multiple folders, getting TypeChoice error

Tags: python, random, pathlib

I'm currently trying to figure out how to sample multiple audio files (sample size of 50+) from a span of *multiple* folders to eventually use to train a model.  Obviously doing this by hand would be very tedious, so I'm trying to figure out how to write a script to do this:

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import random

wav_pathlist = Path(src_dir).glob('**/*.wav')
lab_pathlist = Path(src_dir).glob('**/*.lab')

random_wav_list = []

for i in range(1, int(sample_size)):
    random_wav_list.append(random.choice(wav_pathlist))

print(random_wav_list)
```

What my current approach is is to use reservoir sampling via pathlib to try and get random samples.  I am able to get the file paths, but they are coming back in PosixPath form.  I have been able to extract the file path strings through casting, although I am stuck at one error when trying to get a random sample; using `random.choice()` should get me a random sample of a set amount of file paths, but this is giving the error: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`, and I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Edit: in response to an answer posted below, I have tried casting to a list like shown below

```
random_wav_list = []

for i in range(1, int(sample_size)):
    random_wav_list.append(random.choice(list(wav_pathlist)))
```

it gives me `IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence`

Comment: That error arises if wav_pathlist is empty. i.e there are no files that match your glob string in that directory

Comment: Additionally, I don't know if it matters but your sampling method will contain repeats as calling random.choice many times does nothing to prevent the same item being selected more than once. You can instead use numpy and the numpy.random.choice function like so rather than a for loop.  `random_wav_list = numpy.random.choice(list(wav_pathlist),size=sample_size,replace=False)` Where replace can be True instead if you don't care about duplicates

Comment: For the numpy method, are you assuming that the elements of `wav_pathlist` are numbers?  Because in my case they aren't, they're file paths (i.e., Strings)

Comment: Also I should mention again from my original post that `wav_pathlist` the elements, without casting them, are in `PosixPath` form so you need to cast them to `str` first, which isn't done in your numpy code

Comment: It is fine for numpy random choice if they are strings. And yes, you should cast them to strings first

Answer (score 0):

Try casting wav_pathlist as a list.

```
wav_pathlist = list(wav_pathlist)
for i in range(1, int(sample_size)):
    random_wav_list.append(random.choice(wav_pathlist))
```

It is currently a generator object. random.choice uses a len() operation in order to select a random element of a iterable but generators do not support the len function by design. You can read more about generators here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Casting a generator as a list will often defeat the purpose of a generator (avoiding creating and storing the entire iterable in memory) but for your use-case this should be fine

Comment: Edited my original question above.  Gives me an `IndexError`

Comment: replying to your comment on the original question,  printing the list itself or its length seems to work.  Actually think I fixed the original issue by your comment, saving it as a separate variable